# How to put data on line chart when x axis and data has a time range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I need to create a linechart using d3 in which x-axis will have Time in format `%H:%M:%S` with the interval of 1 hour. I'm using `d3.svg.line` to draw line on graph. X and Y axis both are getting plotted correctly but line is not going to draw, getting exception.

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number...

xLable values are not getting converted into line path?

```js
var elementid = "#linechart";
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 90, left: 30};
var width = $(elementid).innerWidth()  - (margin.left + margin.right);
var height = $(elementid).innerHeight() - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

var data = [{xLabel: "00:30:00", yLabel: 50},
    {xLabel: "04:00:20", yLabel: 12},
    {xLabel: "10:00:00", yLabel: 10},
    {xLabel: "14:20:00", yLabel: 5},
    {xLabel: "15:30:10", yLabel: 11},
    {xLabel: "17:00:00", yLabel: 12},
    {xLabel: "19:00:00", yLabel: 30},
    {xLabel: "22:00:00", yLabel: 25}];

var x = d3.time.scale()
.nice(d3.time.day)
.range([0, width - margin.left - margin.right]);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.yLabel;
  })]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
      .ticks(d3.time.hours,1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var svg = d3.select(elementid)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(-65)"
  });  

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Define the line
  var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.xLabel);
  })
    .y(function (d) {
    return y(d.yLabel);
  });

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));
```

```css
html,body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:none; padding:none; }
#linechart { width:95%; height:95%; margin:none; padding:none; }

path {
     stroke: steelblue;
     stroke-width: 2;
     fill: none;
 }
 .axis path, .axis line {
     fill: none;
     stroke: grey;
     stroke-width: 1;
     shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="linechart" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the `xLabel` in you data are not in the correct format. You have to parse the strings into the date format.

```
 data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.xLabel = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse(d.xLabel);
      d.yLabel = d.yLabel;
 });
```

and I changed this line a little bit (based on [dealing with dates on d3.js axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8301531/dealing-with-dates-on-d3-js-axis))

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([data[0].xLabel, data[7].xLabel]).range([0,  
    width - margin.left - margin.right]);
```

```js
var elementid = "#linechart";
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 90, left: 30};
var width = $(elementid).innerWidth()  - (margin.left + margin.right);
var height = $(elementid).innerHeight() - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

var data = [{xLabel: "00:30:00", yLabel: 50},
    {xLabel: "04:00:20", yLabel: 12},
    {xLabel: "10:00:00", yLabel: 10},
    {xLabel: "14:20:00", yLabel: 5},
    {xLabel: "15:30:10", yLabel: 11},
    {xLabel: "17:00:00", yLabel: 12},
    {xLabel: "19:00:00", yLabel: 30},
    {xLabel: "22:00:00", yLabel: 25},
    {xLabel: "23:30:00", yLabel: 25}];

 data.forEach(function(d) {
      d.xLabel = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse(d.xLabel);
      d.yLabel = d.yLabel;
 });
 
 var startDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse("00:00:00");
  
  var endDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse("23:00:00");
  
var x = d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, endDate]).range([0,  width - margin.left - margin.right]);

var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.yLabel;
  })]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
      .ticks(d3.time.hours,1).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S"));

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

var svg = d3.select(elementid)
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".15em")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "rotate(-65)"
  });  

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Define the line
  var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.xLabel);
  })
    .y(function (d) {
    return y(d.yLabel);
  });

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline(data));
```

```css
html,body { width:100%; height:100%; margin:none; padding:none; }
#linechart { width:95%; height:95%; margin:none; padding:none; }

path {
     stroke: steelblue;
     stroke-width: 2;
     fill: none;
 }
 .axis path, .axis line {
     fill: none;
     stroke: grey;
     stroke-width: 1;
     shape-rendering: crispEdges;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="linechart" />
```

Comment: Thanks Colin, it's almost done. But x domain is not creating time from "00:00:00" and "23:00:00". So if something comes on "23:00:00", line will move out of the graph.

Comment: Ok I added an entry to the data and it worked. Is it ok now (I didnt understand your problem completly)

Comment: Actually as per requirement, i need to show xaxis ticks from "00:00:00" to "23:00:00" even if data is not having any value of "23:xx:xx". After adding "23:00:00" on data, scale is showing "23:00:00" on the bottom but without that entry it's not.

Comment: have a look now. I added 2 variables. If you don't want the value above 23:00:00 you have to remove it in another way, I think.

Comment: Amazingly resolved my problem. This is what i wanted, Thanks buddy!